# Transpose of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following DataFrame -

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[11132,'Jim','Jan',2012,2,'A'],[11132,'Jim','Jan',2012,5,'U'],
[11132,'Jim','Feb',2012,6,'Z'],[11132,'Jim','Feb',2012,4,'A'],
[2755,'Jack','Apr',2012,1,'U'],[2755,'Jack','Apr',2012,3,'A'],[2755,'Jack','Apr',2012,1,'Z'],
[9753,'Sue','Jan',2012,8,'U'],[9753,'Sue','Feb',2012,1,'Z'],[9753,'Sue','Jan',2012,5,'A'],],columns=['ID_Patient', 'Name_Patient','month','year','var','visits'])

df
Out[744]: 
   ID_Patient Name_Patient month  year  var visits
0       11132          Jim   Jan  2012    2      A
1       11132          Jim   Jan  2012    5      U
2       11132          Jim   Feb  2012    6      Z
3       11132          Jim   Feb  2012    4      A
4        2755         Jack   Apr  2012    1      U
5        2755         Jack   Apr  2012    3      A
6        2755         Jack   Apr  2012    1      Z
7        9753          Sue   Jan  2012    8      U
8        9753          Sue   Feb  2012    1      Z
9        9753          Sue   Jan  2012    5      A
```

How to convert it into:

```
df_altered
Out[748]: 
   ID_Patient Name_Patient month  year    U    A    Z
0       11132          Jim   Jan  2012  5.0  2.0  NaN
1       11132          Jim   Feb  2012  NaN  4.0  6.0
2        2755         Jack   Apr  2012  1.0  3.0  1.0
3        9753          Sue   Jan  2012  8.0  5.0  NaN
4        9753          Sue   Feb  2012  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

I was trying to solve it using the following Approach, but to no avail.

> .set_index(....).unstack()

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished using the above aforementioned functions?
Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, you are right - need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID_Patient', 'Name_Patient','month','year','visits'])['var']
         .unstack()
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df1)
   ID_Patient Name_Patient month  year    A    U    Z
0        2755         Jack   Apr  2012  3.0  1.0  1.0
1        9753          Sue   Feb  2012  NaN  NaN  1.0
2        9753          Sue   Jan  2012  5.0  8.0  NaN
3       11132          Jim   Feb  2012  4.0  NaN  6.0
4       11132          Jim   Jan  2012  2.0  5.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, once again. I 'almost' wrote the same code with nearly the same column indices, but probbaly messed up somewhere in between. Many many thanks Sir.

Comment: Jezrael, I was examining my solution, and where mine differed with yours was that you had used `['var']` before `.unstack()`. Can you please explain the reasoning behind that? I don't understand this part.

Comment: Sure, if omit `'var'` difference is you get `Multiindex` in columns - first level is `var` and second levels are `A, U, Z` columns. Is is used if need transform multiple columns (like `var`, `var1`). then need omit `var`, because neet transform all columns. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pivot_table` like

```
In [2781]: df.pivot_table(index=['ID_Patient', 'Name_Patient','month','year'], 
                          columns='visits', values='var').reset_index()
Out[2781]:
visits  ID_Patient Name_Patient month  year    A    U    Z
0             2755         Jack   Apr  2012  3.0  1.0  1.0
1             9753          Sue   Feb  2012  NaN  NaN  1.0
2             9753          Sue   Jan  2012  5.0  8.0  NaN
3            11132          Jim   Feb  2012  4.0  NaN  6.0
4            11132          Jim   Jan  2012  2.0  5.0  NaN
```

Comment: I think `pivot_table` here is a bit problematic - it could aggregate values of table to mean and OP dont know it. And in my opinion this behaviour is dangerous - code do something different as OP think. @Zero - What do you think?

Comment: You could use `df.pivot(..)` instead for such a scenario.

Comment: I am trying to remove index name `visits` by doing `dataFrame.index.name=None` and  `del dataFrame.index.name`, but None works. I Need to remove this index name 'visits'. Could you Folks tell me where I am making the mistake? Thanks!!

Comment: `dataFrame.name=None` solves this issue. Now, `visits` will be removed. This `visits` is actually the name of the columns -- ['ID_Patient','Name_Patient','month','year','A','U','Z']